# Geometric Mean of Uniform random variables convergence

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, convergence

I am doing some independent study in asymptotic statistics and point estimation and am aware that you can get from log transformations of uniform random variables (exponential) all the way up to chi-squared distributions but I came across an intriguing question and I'm not sure how to handle it. I was thinking CLT or Delta Method but am unsure of myself. The thing I am trying to sort out is:

Given $X_1,\ldots X_n\overset{iid}{\sim}Uniform(0,\theta)$ and $Z_n=\left(\prod_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^{1/n}$ what is an example of a function of $Z_n$, i.e. $g(Z_n)$, so that $g(Z_n)\overset{d}{\rightarrow}\chi_{(1)}^2$, where $\overset{d}{\longrightarrow}$ denotes convergence in distribution and $\chi_{(1)}^2$ is a chi-squared random variable with 1 degree of freedom?

Maybe something like $g(h(Z_n))$ where $h(Z_n)\overset{d}{\rightarrow}Normal(0,1)$ and $g(t)=t^2$? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like routine book-work requiring a `self-study` tag to me. Please [take a look](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and either add the tag or explain the source of the question.

Comment: I'd approach this by first taking out a factor of $\theta$ ($Y_i=X_i/\theta$), and working with $-\log Y$ (whereupon the GM will become the negative of an arithmetic mean of exponential(1) variables), and from which a simple manipulation gets you to a chi-square. You should be able to see how $\theta$ comes into it after that, by going back to $X$ in terms of $Y$.